# Python - Insert list of tuples into one column in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I've researched similar links, but still can't figure this out. Most of the other links are trying to insert into multiple rows or columns, but I need this list of tuples in one column.

```
word_in_python = cat
listOfTuples = [('word1', 12), ('word2', 14), ('word3', 4), ('word5', 23)]
```

Here is my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO saved_words (word, data) VALUES (?, ?)", (word_in_python, [listOfTuples]))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I need the INSERT OR IGNORE because the word column is a unique column so duplicate words should not be entered into the db.

I've tried changing to:

```
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO saved_words (word, data) VALUES (?, ?)", (word_in_python, (listOfTuples, )))

c.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO saved_words (word, data) VALUES (?, ?)", (word_in_python, [listOfTuples]))

for each in listOfTuples:
  c.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO saved_words (word, data) VALUES (?, ?)", (word_in_python, (each[0], each[1]) ))
```

None of these work.

The error I am typically getting is:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 5 supplied.
```

I'm also confused by this error. I understand that (?, ?) in my execute line means I am trying to input 2 bindings. My list of tuples has 10 tuples in it, so I am not sure where the 5 supplied bindings are coming from.

Also, my saved_words table had the data column as type BLOB. I thought this would be best for inserting a list.

**EDIT**

What I want is word_in_python (cat) in one column and in the next column listOfTuples, this is all in one row.

Comment: What is `word_in_python`?

Comment: @alecxe it is a separate string I am inputting into another column. While debugging, I tested out inserting just the word_in_python into the db and it worked fine. I believe my error is in inserting listOfTuples.

Comment: A list is not a blob. How exactly should the list look like when it is stored in the DB?

Comment: @CL. the column for the list should include the entire list in one record and one column.

Comment: SQLite does not have a list [data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

Comment: @CL. yeah, that is why I used BLOB. I was thinking it might be able to hold a list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `word_in_python` is, but the correct way to pass a list of tuples to `executemany` is this:

```
c.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO saved_words (word, data) VALUES (?, ?)", listOfTuples))
```

In this case, the database driver would execute a statement for every tuple in the list using tuple items as query parameters - `word1` for `word`, `12` for `data`, then `word2` for `word`, `14` for data etc.

Comment: I've edited to post to explain word_in_python. It is actually a separate string and not the first word in the tuple.